# Determine the similarity of two strings

Tags: python

lets say I have a long string str_1:

```
**str_1** : 'Computer once meant a person who did computations, but now the term almost universally refers to automated electronic machinery. The first section of this article focuses on modern digital electronic computers and their design'
```

and I have a string str_2 to look for in the long string:

```
**str_2** : 'The second section of this article focuses on modern digital electronic computers and their design'
```

The str_2 actually exist in the str_1 but the word 'second' in str_2 is written as 'first' in str_1 the only difference is this.

What I want is to search a sentence in a string with some errors. I want to find the str with some percentage of errors then I will check the mistakes. Is there a way to do this.  Thank you.

Comment: use an algorithm or a library which computes string distance, i.e levenshtein, etc...

Comment: Without any code, this becomes a programming problem. Unfortunately stackoverflow primarily exists to help people get their code working. In the most general cases this seems like a rather difficult problem, to which there are known solutions.

Comment: I duped you to the canonical 'fuzzy string comparison' post. I'd go with the `fuzzywuzzy` or `fuzzyset` libraries here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jaccard similarity score between sentences to determine the similarity between the two.
[Link Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regex like

```
The (?:first|second) section of this article focuses on modern digital electronic computers and their design
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/I0j5ty/1/).

---

However, this seems like some text / corpus problem so you might narrow down the sentences and use other "fuzzy" logic.